# Cannot call FileProvider's getUriForFile in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am encountered a strange behavior in Kotlin
 when creating a custom File provider like this

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
class MyFileProvider: FileProvider()
```

I cannot make this call `MyFileProvider.getUriForFile(...`
Android studio cannot resolve the reference fro getUriForFile

But with java it works

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getUriForFile()` is static
Kotlin doesn't inherit static methods, as there's no such thing as `static` in Kotlin, and you can't really inherit them.
But you can simply use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`